# How do I launch software to edit a texture image used in a node?

Tags: texturing

I wanted to edit a texture used in a node but could not find where to launch it to Photoshop from Blender. I had to open and navigate folders from Windows.

With 2.8x I can't find such a thing. Where is it located?

Comment: Have you set the image editor in _`preferences > FilePaths > Applications > Image Editor`_?  then from the image editor can _Image > Edit Externally_

Comment: @batFINGER Right! The UV editor of course! But strangely at the time I was looking for a way to edit my nodes in the shader editor. I was opening the folder but then you could not launch it from the Blender file browser or even have the browser launch the OS equivalent file browser. I'd love to see a little arrow in the node that would launch the texture image editor of choice. Or even better have a thumbnail of the image in the node that you could click on to edit.

Comment: @batFINGER New problem has occured I added photoshop.exe failed to open. I'll have to find out now what is causing the error. Controlled folder access was in the OFF position. Any suggestions?